# XSL Transformation for-each doesn't work

Tags: xml, xslt, osb

Please guys, could you help me with an xsl transformation.
I have tried everything, but it doens't work.
The source xml:

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>111</ID>
  <F_I>11</F_I>
  <NAME>sometext</NAME>
  <CODE>text</CODE>      
  <CARD_PRODUCTS>
   <CARD_PRODUCTS_ROW>
    <ID>111</ID>
    <F_I>11</F_I>
    <NAME>text</NAME>
    <CODE>text</CODE>        
   </CARD_PRODUCTS_ROW>
   <CARD_PRODUCTS_ROW>
    <ID>111</ID>
    <F_I>11</F_I>
    <NAME>text</NAME>
    <CODE>text</CODE>        
   </CARD_PRODUCTS_ROW>
   ...
  </CARD_PRODUCTS>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

It must be converted (1:1 scheme, just renamed elements) from:

```
<xs:element name="ROWSET" type="mule:ROWSET"/>
   <xs:complexType name="ROWSET">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="ROW" type="mule:ROW" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>         
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="ROW">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="F_I" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="NAME" type="mule:string256"/>
         <xs:element name="CODE" type="mule:CODE"/>             
         <xs:element name="CARD_PRODUCTS" type="mule:CARD_PRODUCTS"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="CARD_PRODUCTS">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="CARD_PRODUCTS_ROW" type="mule:CARD_PRODUCTS_ROW" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="CARD_PRODUCTS_ROW">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="F_I" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="NAME" type="mule:string256"/>
         <xs:element name="CODE" type="mule:CODE"/>             
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```

to:

```
<xs:element name="SalaryProducts" type="sapr:SalaryProducts"/>
   <xs:complexType name="SalaryProducts">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="SalaryProduct" type="sapr:SalaryProduct" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>         
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="SalaryProduct">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="finInstId" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="name" type="sapr:string256"/>
         <xs:element name="productCode" type="sapr:productCode"/>
         <xs:element name="CardProducts" type="sapr:CardProducts"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="CardProducts">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="CardProduct" type="sapr:CardProduct" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="CardProduct">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="finInstId" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="name" type="sapr:string256"/>
         <xs:element name="productCode" type="sapr:productCode"/>             
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <tns:SalaryProducts>
         <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:ROWSET/ns0:ROW">
            <tns:SalaryProduct>
               <tns:id>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:ID"/>
               </tns:id>
               <tns:finInstId>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:F_I"/>
               </tns:finInstId>
               <tns:name>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:NAME"/>
               </tns:name>
               <tns:productCode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:CODE"/>
               </tns:productCode>                   
               <tns:CardProducts>
                  <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:ROWSET/ns0:ROW/ns0:CARD_PRODUCTS/ns0:CARD_PRODUCTS_ROW">
                     <tns:CardProduct>
                        <tns:id>
                           <xsl:value-of select="ns0:ID"/>
                        </tns:id>
                        <tns:finInstId>
                           <xsl:value-of select="ns0:F_I"/>
                        </tns:finInstId>
                        <tns:name>
                           <xsl:value-of select="ns0:NAME"/>
                        </tns:name>
                        <tns:productCode>
                           <xsl:value-of select="ns0:CODE"/>
                        </tns:productCode>                            
                     </tns:CardProduct>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </tns:CardProducts>
            </tns:SalaryProduct>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </tns:SalaryProducts>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Looks like xslt is ok (in my opinion), but it just doesnt work. The only thing that JDeveloper says is: "Missing required child SalaryProduct inside of element tns:SalaryProducts".

Any help would be appreciated. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your stylesheet has no `<xsl:stylesheet>` start tag. And your input does not have any namespaces, so why does your stylesheet use a prefix?

Comment: It has <xsl:stylesheet>. I've missed it here for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rename the elements the easiest way is to define a template for each ("old") element which creates a new element with new name.

```
<xsl:template match="oldname">
  <xsl:element name="newname">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Additionally you need a template for everything else: text, attributes (if there are any...)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="ROWSET">
      <xsl:element name="SalaryProducts">
          <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROW">
      <xsl:element name="SalaryProduct">
          <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ... all other element "mappings" -->

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

(You can try it here: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5DS)

In your examples you are using some namespaces. I recommand you to learn more about them. But in this case I can't find any reason to use any namespace and I think that you are using them in your xsl was not intended.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for help. The problem is solved.
Really, the problem was in namespace 'ns0:' in xsl expressions.
So there are 2 ways to solve the issue:

1. Delete 'ns0:' in xsl.
2. Assign namespace to each element of xml using OSB element 'Rename' (XPath expression .//*) like in this article: http://yuanmengblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/replace-rename-namespace-in-osb.html. It's more complicated, but can be useful for some reasons.